# jQuery ready not working in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

### Context

I have a Rails 3 app I'm working on and have the 'jquery-rails' gem installed and

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

in my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file.

Alerts and coffeescript work ok IF they are base level items.

I've put them into app/assets/javascripts/application.js directly, app/assets/javascripts/pages.js *and* tried it as a coffeescript version in app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee (just changed the file name)

As soon as I put them in something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('works');
});
```

or (for coffeescript)

```
jQuery ->
  alert "hi"
```

**It will not fire at all.**

I've also tried including the jquery file in the application layout but same problems.

### Question

Is there a different syntax for declaring jQuery functions within rails?
Does anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put your js code?

Comment: I'm not that used to looking for java errors in the browser.

It says "Modernizr is not defined" and it links to Foundation.js:32
I'm using the Foundation framework from zurb.

Comment: Just added modernizr manually to my javascripts and now the error has gone, still testing to see if it resolved the issue.

Comment: Wow. That was all it was. That was driving me crazy.
Adding modernizr seems to have solved the issue.
Thanks Speransky.

Comment: You should take a look at this post:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219484/rails-4-jquery-ready-not-firing

Comment: You should take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think coffee script does not work because it should be in file with appropriate extension.

Answer (score 3):

You spelled function wrong:

```
// $(document).ready(funtion(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: That was a typo in posting the question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check the console log as Speransky mentioned, it was calling for modernizr because I had added the Foundation 3 framework manually. It couldn't get modernizr and so was somehow killing my jQuery powers.

I downloaded modernizr.js to app/assets/javascripts, I then added it before the tree:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require modernizr
//= require_tree .
```

That did it.

Answer (score 0):

Another common mistake: change .coffee to .js and forget to remove the top comments.