# Rails 4: JQuery .ready Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

No solutions on stackoverflow seem to be working for my issue here, though I am likely missing something basic. I can't seem to get JQuery's .ready function to fire in my Rails 4 application.

I have tried the following solutions in custom.js:

1.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  alert("hello, world")
});
```

2.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  alert("Hello, world!")
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

3.

```
$(function() {
  alert("Hello, world!")
});
```

4.

```
window.onload=function(){ alert("Hello, javascript onload!") };
```

My application.js manifest looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require custom
//= require plugins
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
```

Console log shows:

```
 TypeError: $ is not a function application.js:22
```

Generated source includes:

```
       <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

If I put this into custom.js, it works:

```
  alert("Hello, world!");
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for runtime errors?

Comment: Check in browser console, that js file with your ready function is loaded.

Comment: Error console message now included.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't recommend adding any js code to `application.js` as that is a manifest file. Simply create a new file, for example, `core.js.coffee` and try

```
$ -> alert 'Hello World!'
```

Sprockets in Rails takes all your js / coffee files and puts them into a compressed and minified single file in production.

Comment: I am not intending to add code permanently to application.js. The issue persists outside of application.js. I am testing in application.js for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Your Gemfile has everything you need for the bundler. Try `bundle install` as it seems to be missing something. Finally, in your Dev Tools inside the browser are you seeing jQuery? I recommend using `gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'` to lock it in to a specific gem version.

Comment: bundle install was used. JQuery appears in the generated source, and first. I've added it for clarity.

Comment: I've also locked in `'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'` with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. It looks like my jquery.js file that I included in the assets folder was conflicting with the jquery gem. I deleted the jquery file, and changed the syntax to:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { alert("Hello, world!") });
```

Comment: Awesome, Rails has its own jQuery code through the gem. That is why it is a good idea to lock it in in case of future updates that may break the app. You could also be fancy and do `$(function () { alert('Hello, world!'); });` but I digress.